# Does the Compulsion spell affect as many creatures as desired?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The spell ***Compulsion*** says

> Creatures of your choice that you can see within range and that can hear you must make a Wisdom saving throw. <...> On a failed save, a target is affected by this spell

Does this mean that the spell can affect as many creatures as the caster desires, provided that they are within range and the caster can see them, and the targets can hear the caster?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Correct, you can target as many creatures as satisfy the conditions. For reference, the relevant rules on spell targets are:

> A typical spell requires you to pick one or more targets
>   to be affected by the spell’s magic. A spell’s description
>   tells you whether the spell targets creatures, objects, or a
>   point of origin for an area of effect (described below).

The spell's description tells us that targets are

> Creatures of your choice that you can see within range and that can hear you [...]

The range of *Compulsion* is 30 feet, so you can target as many creatures as there are within 30 feet of you, provided that you can see them and they can hear you.

Comment: Thanks, just seemed weird that it didn't give a maximum number or anything.

Comment: @PurpleVermont Well, while "creatures within 30 feet" has a theoretical maximum of over 1000 (assuming my maths is correct), it's not that often that you'll have more than a few creatures that close to you. That said, if you're in the middle of a crowd there are some seriously fun use cases for this...

Comment: 1,000? I don't think the wizard would have such good eye sight... and that's if all creatures are flying and all within 5 ft. of each others. I don't think that happens too often, even in a plane.

Comment: @AlexisWilke ...that's kind of my point.